# camera error mmal: Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x4f525245

Tags: camera

I try to take picture with my raspberry camera, I got this error

```
mmal: Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x4f525245
```

any idea???

Comment: Death by static electricity, I fear.

Comment: I've encountered this error now on two camera modules and two different pis. I find it a little hard to believe that it is purely down to static. When the second module went, it had been working perfectly, and then all of a sudden started giving me this error without me having handled it. I would not chuck it, until the source of this error is confirmed, and maybe a webcam is a more robust option in the meantime?

Comment: I have the same problem. looking for solution