# How to fix error code for Raspicam (0x4f525245)?

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

When using my Raspberry Pi, my camera stopped working and I get the following error. [image: Error] For those who cannot read it, it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 277, in 'calling callback function' File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 129, in _control_callback "Received unexpected camera control callback event, Ox%08x" % buf[0].cmd) picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x4f525245 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Desktop/turflnl.py", line 49, in  camera.capture('test.jpg') File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1575, in capture 'Timed out waiting for capture to end') picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end >»1

Upon research of this question,  found the following [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15423/camera-error-mmal-received-unexpected-camera-control-callback-event-0x4f525245), where a comment states that the error is static electricity damage. I find this unlikely, seeing that the camera was in a case and I did not touch the camera for some time. I found this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-new-raspbian-release/) on the Raspberry Pi Foundation Website, which states:

> Also note, this experimental driver may break Raspberry Pi Camera and video playback support, and perhaps other GPU functionality.

I also found this [thread](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/39609/l/mmal-received-unexpected-camera-control-callback-event-0x4f525245?displayFullThread=true) on the Element 14 forums. Which links to [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1335530-kernels-3-10-w1_gpio-destroys-i2c-bus-0-raspicam-doesn-t-work-anymore), which lists instructions I do not know how to do. If anyone could tell me which commands to type in the terminal, that could be great. On this forum [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=75312), I followed all the commands that were provided, with no resolution. What can I do to get my camera functional again?

Edit: I do not have OpenGL enabled on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: That comment only relates to the opengl and you should be able to turn it off in `raspi-config`. For future reference ALWAYS make a backup before a major update. I think there was even a warning in the post. I always backup before any update, because sometimes things can go wrong, even if there is nothing wrong with the update.  PS I didn't read your error - because it is too small. Always pase as text not an image.

Comment: @Milliways I do not have opengl enabled, I thought that the way that it was worded was that the new release may not support raspicam.